# Multiple Token Provider in 1 java class in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-security

i want to ask you about spring security.
so i have this class for configure HttpSecurity called TestSecurityConfiguration and for example i have 2 token providers, ATokenProvider and BTokenProvider. so can i register that 2 token provider in 1 file class TestSecurityConfiguration ?

```
class TestSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private ATokenProvider A;

  @Autowired
  private BTokenProvider B;

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {....}

  @Override
  protected void configToken(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(A);
    auth.authenticationProvider(B);
  }
}
```

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can register 2 providers.

But you should implement the `supports` method to support different `Authentication`, `AuthenticationManager` will test the provider by `supports` method first, if true, the provider will handle the `Authentication`.